# jenkins - How to deactivate case sensitivity to get matches

Tags: jenkins

I added this archive artifacts step in my job

```
 archiveArtifacts 'BUILD/**/*.*'
```

Got the following error:

```
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "BUILD/**/*.*". 
Configuration error?
ERROR: ‘BUILD/**/*.*’ doesn’t match anything because it is treated case 
sensitively. You can deactivate case sensitivity to get matches
```

The issue was that i had used all upper case and it ran fine after i updated that.

My question is how do i deactivate case sensitivity to get matches ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jenkins pipelines, if you want to use the `archiveArtifacts` step in a case insensitive way you'd call it like this (as described [in the manual](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#-archiveartifacts-%20archive%20the%20artifacts)):

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'BUILD/**/*.*', caseSensitive: false
```